# Как исправить проблему с заливкой в Blender?

Tags: svg, 3d, blender

В Blender импортируется SVG, но бывают вот такие баги с заливкой.
Оригинал выглядит так:
[image: original]
После импорта в Blender:
[image: im1]
[image: im2]
[image: im3]
Непонятно в каких точках происходит изменение заливки и при каких условиях
Может кто-то сталкивался?

Comment: Похоже на то, что в SVG модели всего несколько контуров с овер9000 точек. Попробуйте разбить и импортировать по частям.

Answer (score 2):

Это из-за самопересечений линий в мелком масштабе

Попробуйте мой аддон:

https://multlabs.ru/blog/addon-crd

https://github.com/crantisz/blender-curve-remove-doubles-addon

Он удаляет рядом стоящие точки кривой, в 95% случаев это решает проблему. Если не решило, обычно остается 1-2 точки, которые можно удалить вручную, или покрутить distance.

NOTE Обычно svg импортируется в мелком масштабе, поэтому стандартный distance сносит всю модель целиком. Чтобы этого не было, отмасштабируйте объекты до нормальных величин и примените масштаб (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)

Comment: Спасибо, попробуем поэкспериментировать!